# Upload files to google cloud storage (php curl)

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, postman, php-curl

Hi i have created my google cloud storage account to use it to store videos and files, i use this rest api ( http://acquired-backup-198200.appspot.com/upload?uname=arun@gmail.com ) The file uploaded by sending it in the request body ( filename = file ) when i tried to use postman to do that it's successfully uploaded with this php curl code

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://acquired-backup-198200.appspot.com/upload?uname=arun@gmail.com",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"current-logo.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Postman-Token: 0c28e4e9-ac5d-42b9-9f7a-928b32bb3464",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Then i wanted to integrate that code to my site to upload files via my website but the file uploaded empty ( 0bytes) I don't know what is the problem with that so if you can help me improve that code to successfully upload files or you have another working code to do that successfully.

Thanks in advance.....